# In PyCharm Professional, where did the ability to run docker and docker-compose Python interpreters go?

Tags: python, docker, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I've just upgraded to PyCharm Professional 2018.3.3 - and I've noticed that a critical feature seems to have been removed:

PyCharm professional normally allows Python interpreters to be hosted inside Docker containers, optionally configured by docker-compose. In the latest update, this feature seems to have vanished.

Is there another way to add a Python interpreter that's inside a Docker container? Is this a bug or have JetBrains intentionally removed this feature?

[image]

Comment: Is this something that could come from docker plugin? Is it active?

Comment: The docker and remote-python plugins are both installed and active.

Comment: Seems that you found an answer: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-33677
Would be nice to write an answer here for future readers :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem: The "Docker Python" plugin had been remotely disabled.

Solution: Ensure that the plugin is installed, and enabled.

Possible cause: I was using a plugin which synchronized configuration between installations.